# Service that notifies me if not receive a interaction

Tags: monitoring, devops

I have a list of processes (shell scripts triggered by crons) that are executed periodicaly (daily, hourly, etc...).

Sometimes an infrastructure fail happens, and these processes are not executed.

There are any service that receive an interaction (an ping or http get by example) periodicaly, and notify-me if this not happens?

Comment: Are your processes web servers, apis rest, web applications, static html?

Comment: The processes are shell scripts triggered by cron's.

Comment: OK. Do you need detect if cron service at linux level is working or if shell scripts was triggered? Do your processes take too long?

Comment: I need to detect if my script run without error's, returning zero from shell.

Comment: How do you want to be notified with the script result : simple log, sql table, remote dashboard, mail, telegram bot, slack, git repository , sms, etc ?

Comment: An simple e-mail email solves the problem. Telegram bot, slack, sms are good options too.